# Prevent Scaling up bootstrap card with an image when card-text is long

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

as you can see i have a image inside of a card, the image size is fixed and known but the card-text length might vary (short or too long).
the question is how can i prevent card height to scale up and force it to keep the height to just contain image and force the text to be wrapped and shorten.

[image: image of card]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container body-content">
 <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header" style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;font-size:large" dir="rtl">
            <p style="padding-right:20px;margin-bottom:0px">Post Header</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-right:0px">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-9">
                    <p style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;text-align:right;white-space: normal;" dir="rtl" class="card-text">
                        This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long TextThis Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://fakeimg.pl/200/">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean the height of image fit to text height?

Comment: @לבנימלכה no image size is fixed, and card height must be a value to fit the image not text, now if text is too long just cut the text and not scale up to contain the whole text

Answer (score 2):

Using the property `overflow:hidden` and dynamically setting the height of the div solves the problem. Add `onresize="myFunction()"` and `onload="myFunction()"` to your body tag.

```js
function myFunction()
{
 var a=document.getElementById("image").height;
 document.getElementById("test").style.height = a+"px";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body onresize="myFunction()" onload="myFunction()">
<div class="container body-content">
 <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header" style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;font-size:large" dir="rtl">
            <p style="padding-right:20px;margin-bottom:0px">Post Header</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-right:0px;max-height:200px !important;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-9" style="overflow:hidden;" id="test">
                    <p style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;text-align:right;" dir="rtl" class="card-text">
                        This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long TextThis Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text This Is Long Text
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://fakeimg.pl/200/" id="image">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a fixed height and hide the overflowing content with `overflow: hidden`. To make things look pretty I also faded out the last few words

```css
.truncate-text {
  position: relative;
  height: 4.6em; /* height of 3 lines of text  */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.truncate-text::after {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  width: 40%;
  height: 1.7em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container body-content">
 <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header" style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;font-size:large" dir="rtl">
            <p style="padding-right:20px;margin-bottom:0px">Post Header</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-right:0px">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-9" style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;text-align:right;white-space: normal;">
                    <div class="truncate-text">
                    <p dir="rtl" class="card-text">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos sint consequatur quidem in blanditiis ab, eaque ad, ducimus quasi laboriosam corporis dolores vero. Tempore explicabo veritatis suscipit ratione ut voluptatem aut consectetur rem eaque cum fuga, sunt distinctio dolorem ducimus ipsum nihil nostrum? Iusto accusamus voluptate culpa vero! Libero saepe necessitatibus, ipsum aut dolores nihil voluptates recusandae. Quibusdam repellendus iste aperiam quas voluptates! Pariatur veritatis inventore debitis sed facere ratione aliquid iste libero nobis ea voluptatum harum delectus, laborum quisquam at aut necessitatibus consequatur explicabo ipsum odio, facilis cum iusto quam! Corrupti soluta amet eligendi labore odit asperiores vel aliquid?
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://fakeimg.pl/200/">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution always shows three lines of text whatever be the size of the screen. The text displayed should be varied according to the size of the image.